# how can i prevent nested list's click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").has("ul").bind("click",function(e){
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
    });
</script>

<ul>
<li>Fruit
    <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I bind click-event only when  Fruit  is clicked, not Apple, Banana

I hope that click-event is not occured when Apple or Banana is clicked

please help me..

Comment: @opalenzuela preventDefault has nothing to do with it. it does not stop propagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, as already illustrated, is with `event.stopPropagation()`. I dislike this method, since it prevents any other event handlers on the page registering the event.

Better is to check to see if the event originated in another `li` element. Something like this would do:

```
$("li").has("ul").bind("click",function(e){
    if ($(e.target).closest('li').get(0) !== this) {
        return;
    }

    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Let's break apart the key line there:

- get `e.target`, the element where the event originated
- make a jQuery object out of it
- check to see if that element is an `li` or get its nearest `li` ancestor ([`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) does this)
- get that `li` as a native DOM element
- compare the `li` to the one where the event handler was bound

If the `li` elements are not the same, the event originated on a nested `li`. If they are the same, it didn't.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/Tt6YN/)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap you 'Fruit' with an element (like span), and bind the event on this element.

From Quentin's advice, use an element that will tell the user that it is interactive (like <button>, <a>), it's better in fact.

Comment: Use an element that is designed to be interactive (like `<button>`), that way it will be in the navigation order for people using non-pointing devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").on("click",function(e){
       alert($(this).text())
    });

     or

     $("ul li").live("click",function(e){
       alert($(this).text())
    }); 

    });
</script>

<ul>
<li>Fruit
    <ul>
        <li>Apple</li>
        <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

No need to prevent. Based on your jquery plugin version use live or on. Both are same. If you use this it'll handle the click event that which element you are clicked.
The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. Use the on() method instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").has("ul").bind("click", function (e) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
    $("li ul").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZS8Dg/)

Another solution without stopping the event propagation is something like(will work for the given markup)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").has("ul").bind("click", function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(e.target)) {
            console.log($(this).text());
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/krvbW/)

Comment: Personally- im **against** attaching another handler just to stop buuble it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("li").has("ul").bind("click",function(e){
        console.log($(this).text());

    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = false;

    //e.stopPropagation works only in Firefox.
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
```

Comment: 2 errors : PreventDefault (caps) and PreventDefault is not helping here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : [**working example**](http://jsbin.com/OBiRodA/3/edit)

```
$("li").has("ul").bind("click", function (e) {

      if (!$(e.target).find("li").length) return;

        console.log($(this).text());

    });
```